# Why isn't the first section heading of my uitableview displayed until the view has loaded?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Header says it all really.  I have a push segue to a tableview (grouped), nested in a navigation controller.  As the segue is happening the table view is missing its first section heading (but the rest are there):

[segue http://mazz0.com/images/xcode/missingsectionheading/segue.PNG](http://mazz0.com/images/xcode/missingsectionheading/segue.PNG)

then once it's appeared it all jumps down to reveal the first section header:

[once_loaded http://mazz0.com/images/xcode/missingsectionheading/once_loaded.PNG](http://mazz0.com/images/xcode/missingsectionheading/once_loaded.PNG)

so presumably something happens in uitableview's viewDidAppear method that I should call in my overridden viewDidLoad method, or there's something I should set in my storyboard?

Comment: Maybe some code will help us to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what code to include - I haven't overridden viewDidAppear so I don't know what's making it work once it's appears, in fact I haven't written any code that changes the display, it's all storyboard.  Here's a screenshot of the storyboard for that tableview:

http://mazz0.com/images/xcode/missingsectionheading/storyboard.png